# Does Interlocked.CompareExchange(double,double,double) work in 32 bit OS?

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking, interlocked

I'm maintaining a high performance class that can be operated on by multiple threads.  Many of the fields are volatile ints, and as it turns out I need to upgrade one of those to a double.  I'm curious if there is a lock free way to do this, and was wondering if the `Interlocked.CompareExchange(double, double, double)` works as advertised on a 32-bit OS, or are torn reads a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttk2z1ws(VS.85).aspx) details the intrinsics of the "native" Interlocked functions. It mentions the following limitations

*Because _InterlockedCompareExchange64 uses the cmpxchg8b instruction, it is not available on pre-Pentium processors, such as the 486.*

So we can expect that it is available and also implemented as an interlocked instruction operation (rather than being simulated by using a full lock).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works as described on 32-bit. That's what the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) methods are there for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's works.

It uses InterlockedCompareExchange64 - if you want to have a look at a possible implementation in x86 asm, have a look here - http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=6212.

```
asm
//     ->          EAX     Destination 
//                 ESP+4   Exchange    
//                 ESP+12  Comperand   
//     <-          EDX:EAX Result      
          PUSH    EBX
          PUSH    EDI

          MOV     EDI, EAX

          MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR [Comperand]
          MOV     EDX, DWORD PTR [Comperand+4]

          MOV     EBX, DWORD PTR [Exchange]
          MOV     ECX, DWORD PTR [Exchange+4]

LOCK      CMPXCHG8B [EDI]

          POP     EDI
          POP     EBX
end;
```

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).